# Text in dynamic text box disappears when animated

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to animate dynamic text. The text is taken from a variable using 
mybox.text = somevar;

The text appears in the box but once the box start moving the text disappears. I have Googled it and all responses seem to be that fonts should be embedded, but I already did that and it doesn't work.

I'm using AS2.

Comment: Have you both set `mybox.embedFonts=true;` and embedded the actual font outline in the library? There must be something wrong with the way you are embedding the fonts - this behavior should not occur when everything is set up correctly.

Comment: Yes I did that. I also tried to fill the variables with LoadVariables from a txt file and it worked (the text was animated as expected).

Comment: Then it's probably not a font problem, but a timing issue. Either the `mybox.text` property is set to "" after the original text appears, or the TextField is removed from the stage at some point (i.e., there's an empty frame somewhere) - in which case, the instance is deleted and re-created, so the variable must be set again.  The way I see it, loading the data would delay setting the variable until the file is completely read, therefore whatever clears the field happens *before* the actual text appears on the stage.

Comment: may be you reseted your `somevar` in realtime?